# Actualizar atributo de un objeto en la vista del componente hijo desde un metodo del padre VUEJS y LARAVEL

Tags: php, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

**Componente padre:**

```js
<template>
 <div>

  <div class="right_col" role="main">
   <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4"> 
     
     <div class="row">
      <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th colspan="5" class="center">SOLICITUD DE PEDIDO</th>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td style="color:red">COD</td>
         <td style="color:red">DESCRIPCION</td>
         <td style="color:red">UNIDAD</td>
         <td style="color:red">PRECIO U.</td>
         <td style="color:red">PRECIO T.</td>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr is="card" v-for="product in cards" :product="product" :key="product.id" ref="card"></tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" v-if="order.length == 3 || order.length == 3 && rol == 2" @click="sendOrder()">Enviar Pedido</button>
      
     </div>
     <div class="row" v-if="order.length == 3">
      <div class="col-sm-12"> 

       <table class="table table-hover">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th colspan="3">PEDIDOS</th>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Descripcion</td>
         <td>Unidad</td>
         <td>Cantidad</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
     </div>      
    </div>
   </div>       
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addCard">Agregar productos</button>  
 </div>

</template>

<script>


 export default{

  data(){
   return {
    cards:[],
    checkClient: [],
    products:[],
    order:[],
    tmpProduct:[],
    filterLine:[],
    filterCategory:[],
    selectLine:'',
    selectCategorie:'',
    urlProduct:'orders/products',
    urlFilterLine:'orders/filterLine',
    urlFilterCategory:'orders/filterCategory',
    urlFilterLineCategory:'orders/filterLineCategory',
    urlFilterCategoryProducts:'orders/filterCategoryProducts',

    unit_total:0,
    base_imponible:0,
    total_excento:0,
    subtotal:0,
    iva:0,
    total:0,


   }
  },
  methods: {
   listProduct(){
    axios.get(this.urlProduct).then( response => {     
     this.products = response.data.products;
    });
  
   },
   addCard:function(){
    //Compruebo que existan productos seleccionados
    if (this.tmpProduct.length == 0) {
     this.message("Debe seleccionar un producto","");
    }else{
     //Compruebo si exiten productos en el carrito
     if (this.cards.length == 0) {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.tmpProduct.length; i++){
       this.cards.push(this.tmpProduct[i]);
      }
      
     }else{
      for(var i = 0; i < this.tmpProduct.length; i++){
       var exists = false;
       for (var e = 0; e < this.cards.length; e++) {
        if (this.cards[e].id == this.tmpProduct[i].id) {
         this.cards[e].cant += parseInt(this.tmpProduct[i].cantTmp);
         console.log(this.cards[e].cant);
         exists = true;
        }
       }
       if (exists == true) {
        continue;
       }
       this.cards.push(this.tmpProduct[i]);
      }
      
     }

     this.totalOrder();
     this.tmpProduct = [];
     if (this.rol == 2){
      this.clientOrder();
     }
     this.check = 1;
     for (var i = 0; i < this.$refs.product.length; i++) {
      this.$refs.product[i].checkClean();
     }
     this.message("Productos agregado a carrito","");
    }
   },
   totalOrder:function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.tmpProduct.length; i++) {
     this.unit_total += parseInt(this.tmpProduct[i].cantTmp);
     var unit = parseInt(this.tmpProduct[i].cantTmp);     
     var sale_price = parseFloat(this.tmpProduct[i].sale_price);
     if (this.tmpProduct[i].apply_iva == true ) {
      var ivaUnit = parseInt(this.oniva) * sale_price / 100;
      this.base_imponible = (unit * sale_price + parseFloat(this.base_imponible)).toFixed(2);
      this.iva += this.round(unit * ivaUnit);
     }else{
      this.total_excento = (unit * sale_price +parseFloat(this.total_excento)).toFixed(2);
     }
     this.subtotal = (unit * sale_price + parseFloat(this.subtotal)).toFixed(2);
     
     this.total =  this.round(parseFloat(this.subtotal) + parseFloat(this.iva));
     
    }
   },
   addProduct: function (product,cant) {
    product.cantTmp = parseInt(cant);
    product.cant = parseInt(cant);    
    this.tmpProduct.push(product);
   },
   changeProduct: function(product,cant){
    if (cant == 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < this.tmpProduct.length; i++) {
      if (this.tmpProduct[i].id == product.id) {
       this.tmpProduct.splice([i],1);
      }
     }
    }else{
     for (var i = 0; i < this.tmpProduct.length; i++) {
      if (this.tmpProduct[i].id == product.id) {
       this.tmpProduct[i].cant = parseInt(cant);
       this.tmpProduct[i].cantTmp = parseInt(cant);
      }
     }
    }
   },


  },
  computed:{

  },

 }


</script>
```

**COMPONENTE HIJO:**

```html
<template>
 <tr>
  <td v-text="product.id"></td>
  <td v-text="product.product_description"></td>
  <td v-text="product.cant"> </td>
  <td v-text="product.sale_price"></td>
  <td>{{product.cant * product.sale_price}}</td>

 </tr>
</template>

<script>

 export default{
  props:['product'],
  data(){
   return {
    carrito: this.product.cant
   }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  watch:{

  },
  computed:{

  },
  mounted(){

  },
 }
</script>
```

Lo que quiero que noten es la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.tmpProduct.length; i++){
                        var exists = false;
                        for (var e = 0; e < this.cards.length; e++) {
                            if (this.cards[e].id == this.tmpProduct[i].id) {
                                this.cards[e].cant += parseInt(this.tmpProduct[i].cantTmp);
                                console.log(this.cards[e].cant);
                                exists = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (exists == true) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        this.cards.push(this.tmpProduct[i]);
                    }

                }
```

Donde compruebo que si existe el producto en el array **cards**, actualizo la variable **cant**, cuando examino el objeto card del componente hijo del props que recibe con la herramienta de vuejs tools del navegador, en efecto suma el valor, pero no se actualiza en la vista del componente hijo automaticamente, y no entiendo porque, si esta recibiendo la el objeto en el props?

En la vista del hijo necesito que se actualice si accedo, la linea que uso es esta:

```
<td v-text="product.cant"> </td>
```

Pero no seactualiza automaticamente, me parece extraño porque hice lo mismo con html y vue desde cdn creando componente padre e hijo y pase variables y luego hice un metodo que aumentara el valor con cada click y si me cambia el valor en el componente hijo... Alguien podria tomarse el tiempo de ver esto?

Lo que necesito que haga es algo similar a esto:

Comment: una cosa son variables.. y otra objetos.. Los objetos no son reactivos en su totalidad, a menos que le apliques un object.set para modificarlo. Esta explicado en el manual de vue, [aca](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: Entiendo, pero aplique un cambio a un objeto en otro ejemplo y si me funciono y aqui estoy haciendo basicamente lo mismo, podria ver lo que indicas de set.

Comment: un objeto es distinto de una variable que no es un objeto, tene en cuenta eso.